# Why can't SnapshotReadyCallback be resolved?

Tags: android, google-maps, snapshot

I've been working with the GoogleMap library for months, so I know the library is imported and working correctly. Now, I'm trying to use

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback;
```

But I get this error:

```
The import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback cannot be resolved
```

This interface is included in the GoogleMap documentation, so why can't my IDE find it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the project target. You might have changed it to `Android` instead of `Google API`. Target SDK must be `Google API`

Comment: No, the target is definitely Google API. Good guess, though.

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild? In all cases someone got this error was setting wrong target.

Comment: Yes, I cleaned several times, and once more after reading your comment for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason could be that you are using an old version of google play services, try to do it using version 4.0.30. Here's a link that might be useful: [Play Services Setup](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)